# Is there something similiar to AffectsRender in a Windows Store App?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime

I have a user control which inside it contains an Image, a TextBox, and a Button.
It implements `MeasureOverride()` and `ArrangeOverride()`, which basically takes the textbox's Text property into account to resize itself.

But... `ArrangeOverride()` and `MeasureOverride()` are only called once, *before* the Text is set. After the Text is changed / updated via data binding, they do not get called again to recalculate.

I know there is an `AffectsRender` metadata flag in WPF, and also a `InvalidateVisual`, but I'm in Windows 8 Runtime land. How can I do this here?

```
protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
{
  Size panelDesiredSize = new Size();

  m_textbox.Measure(availableSize);

  if (m_textbox.DesiredSize.Height < m_textbox.MinHeight)
  {
    panelDesiredSize = new Size(
      m_textbox.DesiredSize.Width, m_textbox.MinHeight);
  }
  else
  {
    panelDesiredSize = m_textbox.DesiredSize;
  }

  return panelDesiredSize;
}

protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)
{
  double x = 0;
  double y = 0;

  m_textbox.Arrange(new Rect(new Point(x, y), finalSize));
  m_button.Arrange(new Rect(new Point(x, y), finalSize));
  m_image.Arrange(new Rect(new Point(x, y), finalSize));

  m_button.Width = finalSize.Width;
  m_button.Height = finalSize.Height;

  m_image.Width = finalSize.Width;
  m_image.Height = finalSize.Height;

  return finalSize; // Returns the final Arranged size
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is similar to the situation in Silverlight. There's no metadata fanciness, you need to set up property change / event handlers on the appropriate elements and trigger invalidation. So for example register an event handler on something like `TextChanged` or `SizeChanged` of the element you're interested in and call one of `InvalidateMeasure`, `InvalidateArrange` or `UpdateLayout` to force a layout cycle.